# Получить максимальную длину поля

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

В сущности указываю:

```
/**Банковские реквизиты*/
@Column(name = "\"someBank\"", length = 300)
private String someBank;
```

В БД `varchar(300)`. Можно ли получить этот `length` из БД/сущности, к примеру для ограничения по количеству символов в поле ввода?

Comment: А паблик файнал статик инт SOME_BANK_LENGTH = 300 не подойдет? Или вы хотите прям из бд забрать запросом длину эту?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov хм, тогда из БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой вот запрос вам вернет тип колонки:

```
SELECT data_type FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' AND column_name = 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME';
```

Дальше из строки `varchar(300)` я думаю не составит труда вытащить значение `300`

UPDATE.
Получить длину из аннотации можно с помощью рефлексии.

```
int length = YourClassName.class.getField("someBank").getAnnotation(Column.class).length()
```

Comment: Разумнее сразу получать `character_maximum_length` либо (вдруг нужно?) `character_octet_length`. См. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/infoschema-columns.html

Comment: Да, спасибо. А все же нельзя получать длину из аннотаций без финальных полей?

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.- можно через рефлексию. Смотри update ответа

Comment: @AndrewBystrov И последний вопрос, как понимаю нельзя в рантайме устанавливать значения в аннотации, дабы значения брались непосредственно из БД?

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.- нет, так не получится, потому что у аннотации нет полей, которые вы можете проставить в рантайме